# Laravel массовый импорт в БД

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, model, insert

**Добрый день!**

**Коротко о системе:** 
laravel: 5.5 
PHP: 7.0 
Модуль: Apache-PHP-7  
БД: MySql-5.7 
ОС: Windows/Linux (тестовый/боевой)

**Задача** такая. 
Подгружается прайс с тысячами позиций, которые необходимо забить в БД, артикул является уникальным ключем. 
При первом проходе файла (уникальных артикулов) все проходит хорошо, но дело в том, что данные могут из файла в файл (временами) повторяться. 
Задача заключается в том, что бы **не делать тысячи запросов к БД, а одним запросом записать только уникальные данные из массива.** 
При обычной вставке типа

```
Goods::insert($dbArr);
```

*будет возвращена ошибка т.к. некоторые ключи могут быть не уникальны*.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '111120150182' for key 'goods_article_unique' (SQL: insert into `goods` (`article`,`collection`, `description`, `imageN`, `name`, `price`, `size`) values (************))
```

Вариант с получением всей коллекции из БД не совсем верен т.к. в БД может быть большое количество записей, сейчас около 10к может быть и и 50к товаров, а это надо понимать не корректно выбирать 50к строк из БД.

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 5.8.33 был добавлен метод `insertOrIgnore`, который пропускает повторяющиеся уникальные поля при добавлении в базу.

```
Goods::insertOrIgnore($dbArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

как то так. если не нужно обновлять значения, то вы можете обновлять поле updated_at

```
function insertOrUpdate($table, array $rows)
{
    $first = reset($rows);
    $columns = implode(',',
        array_map(function ($value) {
            return "$value";
        }, array_keys($first))
    );

    $values = implode(',', array_map(function ($row) {
            return '(' . implode(',',
                    array_map(function ($value) {
                        return '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
                    }, $row)
                ) . ')';
        }, $rows)
    );

    $updates = implode(',',
        array_map(function ($value) {
            return "$value = VALUES($value)";
        }, array_keys($first))
    );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES {$values} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {$updates}";

    return \DB::statement($sql);
}
```

что-то вроде

```
return "updated_at = now()";
```